# proving limit of a probability measure equals measure defined as inf of larger sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Let P be a probability measure of field $\mathcal{F_0}$

Let $\mathcal{G}$ is a class of subset of $\Omega$ s.t. $\mathcal{G}$ is the collection of all limits of increasing sequences in $\mathcal{F_o}$.

Let $\mu^*(A)=inf\{\mu(G): G \in \mathcal{G}, A \subset G\}$

$\mu(A)= lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n),$ where $\{A_n\} \uparrow A.$,

where P is probability measure.

Then $\mu^*=\mu $ on $\mathcal{G}$

I understand $\mu^* \geq \mu$. Is there any intuitive way to show the other direction for completing the proof. Intuitively I am drawing an image in my mind that there should be no gaps in $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ but I do not know how to reach to the equality. Any help with the intuition will be appreciated.

Here is the intuition I have so far:

1. Let $ G'' s.t. A \subset G'' \subset G $
2. Prove that there is a sequence whose limit is $G''$
3. Therefore $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu (G'')$
4. This means it can not be true that $ \mu(A) < \mu^*(A)$ on $\mathcal{G}$

Am I on the right track by any chance? Or is there is any easier way to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

If $A \in \mathcal G$ then $\mu^{*}(A) \leq \mu(A)$ by definition. The infimum of a set is less than nor equal to each element of the set.

Comment: my apologies, I corrected the definition of $\mu^*$